# Animation of 2048 Game in android

Tags: android, graphics

I have made a "2048 game" with java in Eclipse . All things is good and work correctly, even the animation of cells that move in 4 directions.

But the problem is, that the animation does not work fine & smooth, I think because of heavy processing load. 
I have made a class that extends `ImageView`. and I have overridden the
`onDraw()` method. Then in another method and in a thread, I call the `postInvalidate()` method frequently for the animation (so the `onDraw()` method is called frequently). 
My algorithm in the `onDraw()` method is fine and my animation runs correctly but I think using this way (using `ImageView` class and calling `onDraw()` method frequently) is not an accurate way, because the `onDraw()` method redraws everything unnecessarily. Some things in this game are fix and do not need to be redrawn, so this way the process is heavy and I don't like this.

Is there another way for this game, than drawing the page frequently for animation without jumping? thank's for your answer .

Comment: Why use an ImageView? Those are meant for displaying graphics from resources (e.g. PNGs). Why not a custom View (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)?